# Update many to many custom property of a table with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

i'm building an application using Nest Js and TypeOrm. I have a many to many relation between ShoppingList and Item, like this:

ShoppingList

```
@Entity()
export class ShoppingList {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_At' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ default: 'open' })
  status: 'completed' | 'cancelled' | 'open';

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (User) => User.shopping_lists)
  owner: User;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ShoppingListItem,
    (shoppingListItem) => shoppingListItem.shoppingList,
  )
  items: ShoppingListItem[];
}
```

ShoppingListItem:

```
@Entity()
export class ShoppingListItem {
  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @Column()
  checked: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => Item, (item) => item.lists, { primary: true })
  item: Item;

  @ManyToOne(() => ShoppingList, (shoppingList) => shoppingList.items, {
    primary: true,
  })
  shoppingList: ShoppingList;
}
```

Item:

```
@Entity()
export class Item {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => ShoppingListItem,
    (shoppingListItem: ShoppingListItem) => shoppingListItem.item,
  )
  lists: ShoppingListItem[];

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.items)
  category: Category;
}
```

and my point is: HOW could I update the 'checked' custom property in the many to many relation??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you can update it as a normal entity column

```
this.ShoppingListItemRepository.update(id, {checked: true});
```

and you can use this in your ShoppingList service on a Shopping changed, and use {where to find related items}:

ShoppingList service:

```
async updateShoppingList(ShoppingListID: number) {
/...
    const results = await this.ShoppingListItemRepository.find({where:{
        shoppingList : ShoppingListID,
      }});
    const ids = results.map((item)=> item.id);
    await this.ShoppingListItemRepository.update(ids, {checked: true});
```

Comment: ShoppingListItemRepository dont have an id because it's a many-to-many relation table, should i put an id?

Comment: yes, put id,  id is useful for every entity